# BF Interpreter in F# Issue

Tags: f#, brainfuck

Ok so i am working on a small project as you can tell in the title i am making an BrainFuck interpeter in f# and i am new to this language but it is fun except that you fight with the compiler lot but i am used to it cause i used to use rust but aside the point it looks like to me it is only executing the symbols once. I know this is not efficient or fully functional but right now i am just going that works. Here is my code 
main.fs

```ml
open System
open System.IO
let mutable reg : int array = Array.zeroCreate 50
let mutable ptr = 0
let mutable larr : int array = Array.zeroCreate 50
let mutable lptr = 0
let mutable pc = 0
let result = "++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++."
let prog = result.ToCharArray()
let startLoop = 
    larr.[lptr] <- pc
    printfn "STARTING LOOP AT %d" larr.[lptr]
    lptr <- lptr + 1
let doEnd = 
    pc <- larr.[lptr]
    while larr.[lptr - 1] > 0 do
        ptr <- larr.[lptr - 1]
        larr.[lptr - 1] <- larr.[lptr - 1] - 1
let endLoop =
    lptr <- lptr - 1
    if reg.[ptr] = 0 then pc <- pc  
    else doEnd
let doPlus =
    reg.[ptr] <- (reg.[ptr] + 1) % 265
    printfn "ADDING"
let doMinus = 
    reg.[ptr] <- (reg.[ptr] - 1) % 265
    printfn "SUB"
let doInc = 
    ptr <- (ptr + 1) % 265
    printfn "INC"
let doDec = 
    ptr <- (ptr - 1) % 265
    printfn "MINUS"
let doPrt = 
    printfn "%c" (reg.[ptr] |> char)
let doSloop =
    startLoop
    printfn "START LOOP"
let doEloop = 
    endLoop
    printfn "END LOOP"
let exec = 
    while pc < prog.Length do
        let i = prog.[pc]
        if i = '+' then doPlus
        elif i = '-' then doMinus
        elif i = '>' then doInc
        elif i = '<' then doDec
        elif i = '.' then doPrt
        elif i = '[' then doSloop
        elif i = ']' then doEloop
        else 1 |> ignore
        pc <- pc + 1
exec
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you mean that you are just defining values instead of functions? Functions need an input, and they can take `void` if necessary. Define it like this `let exec() =` and call it with `exec()` and this goes for anything else that is a function in your code.

Comment: I think @s952163 is correct. But technically not `void`, but `unit`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/unit-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the F# community.

Here is a more functional style of writing your program. It's just a start, but I hope it will give you some ideas about how to proceed. Ultimately, you'll want to avoid mutable values if at all possible, and probably the first step to doing that would be to write functions that have parameters other than unit.

```
let result = "++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++."

let doPlus () =
    // reg.[ptr] <- (reg.[ptr] + 1) % 265
    printfn "ADDING"

let doMinus () = 
    // reg.[ptr] <- (reg.[ptr] - 1) % 265
    printfn "SUB"

let doDefault () = printfn ""

let funcs = 
    [|
        '+', doPlus
        '-', doMinus
    |] |> Map.ofArray

let exec () =
    result
    |> Seq.iteri (fun i c -> 
        printf "%03d: " i
        match funcs.TryFind(c) with
        | Some func -> func ()
        | None -> doDefault ()
    )
exec ()
```